# How can I shade heading in word document created using Python-docx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I want to create a word document using python-docx package. Since I have many indicators, I want to shade the heading in order to separate paragraphs as shown:[image]

MS-Word has an inbuilt theme called "Shaded" for this purpose.

I have tried `document.add_heading("Heading1")`, but I don't have relevant option to shade the heading in Python. Is it possible to shade the heading using any attribute or property in Python?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. What I did was create a word document called "template.docx"; in the template, I created the headings with the formats wanted, with the shaders, colors, fonts, sizes, etc. (It's not necessary to create content inside the document.) After that, I imported the template into my program, and all the documents I generated from there come in that format.

As you may know, you can even create new styles in the template, and call them later in Python.

The way to import the template is very simple:

```
doc = Document('template.docx')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing in Word as "shading" a paragraph or paragraph style that has the effect you mention of giving a paragraph a "background color".

Unfortunately there is currently no API support for that in `python-docx`.